# If part is not working in AJAX response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using AJAX for login.I am getting proper output from my process page but in AJAX it's responding only else part. Why it's not checking if condition? It's direct going to else part. even I tried

```
if(response == 'true'){}
if(response === "true"){}
if(response === true){}
```

Would you help me in this?

**Process.php**

```
if(condtion){
echo "true";
else {
  echo "Email & Password does not match";
}
```

**ajax.php**

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'process?key=login',
            data: $('.login_submit').serialize(),
           success: function (response) {
          if(response === 'true'){
             $("#login_call").hide();   
             window.location.reload();     
            }else{
              $('.login_error').css('displaay','block');
                $(".login_error").html(response);
              }

            }
          });
```

Comment: Do `alert(response);` in the *success* callback function and see what data you're getting back from the backend PHP page.

Comment: seems you missed a }  in process-php  are you sure you don't have error?

Comment: that part is likely wrong : `data: $('.login_submit').serialize(),`, the jQuery selector should match your `form` element

Comment: @RajdeepPaul, I am getting true in the popup.

Comment: What is your actual PHP, is there a closing `?>`? Try `console.log(response)` and view the console, might be a new line or whitespace in there.

Comment: @scaisEdge, Yes I am sure, There is no } is missing.

Comment: @chris85, I am getting true in console

Comment: With nothing after/before it? Try `if(response.trim() === 'true'){`

Comment: Is that `condition` a pseudo-code for some condition to check, or should it be a php variable called `$condition`?

Comment: @chris85, I tried your code if(response.trim() === 'true'){ and it's working.

Comment: Great, I'll mark this as a dup of another question where I answered that. You probably have `?>` in your PHP which is putting a trailing new line on your return.